# Exclude subclasses from results in the backoffice

Tags: sap-commerce-cloud

I wonder how to exclude subclasses from results in the backoffice.

For example: Employee is extended by custom `ExternalEmployee` class. In the backoffice navigation there is an 'Employees' tab, but it shows every employee, including `ExternalEmployee` objects. I would like to exclude those subclasses.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the backoffice (not hmc) you have a checkbox <kbd>Include subtypes</kbd> in the search bar. Unselect it to only get results of the parent type.